# pass this local js variable as an argument to a new function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, arguments

I've read several posts on passing local function variables to new functions in javascript but am still having trouble in my own particular case.

I'm trying to pass the `term` argument given to `data: function (term, page)` to the `generateUrl` function below it. `this.term = term` and `window.term = term` (which I know is bad practice) aren't working. Should I try to declare a `term` variable outside of `$(document).ready(function)` or outside of the two inner functions, or or should I move the `generateUrl` definition inside of the `$("#example").select2` function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#example").select2({
      ajax: {
          url: generateUrl(),
          data: function (term, page) {
            this.term = term; // i want to pass this local variable to generateUrl
          }
      }
  });

  function generateUrl(term) {
    (function ($) {

    var args = 'keywords=' + term;
    return args;

    }
    (jQuery));
  }
});
```

Comment: Just call generateUrl(term)

Comment: i get "ReferenceError: term is not defined "

Comment: i should have mentioned that i was omitting code for the sake of clarity. just imagine that i want to build a variable "args" within generateUrl with the "term" argument passed to #example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#example").select2({
  ajax: {
      url: generateUrl(), /* You are calling generateUrl without parameter, 
                               this will cause error
                             Did you actualy mean generateUrl(term) ? */
      data: function (term, page) {
        this.term = term; // i want to pass this local variable to generateUrl
        generateUrl( this.term ); /* Is this what you want to do?  */
      }
  }
});

function generateUrl(term) {
  (function ($) {

    var args = 'keywords=' + term;
    return args;

  }
(jQuery));
```

}
});

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work (still Uncaught ReferenceError: term is not defined )

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the [select2 documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), the example on section "Loading Remote Data" seems to be exactly what you're looking for. Based on that, I believe your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#example").select2({
      ajax: {
          url: "", // replace that empty string with your ajax base url 
                   // (without any parameters)
          data: function (term, page) {
              return { keywords : term };
          }
      }
  });
});
```